# How to deploy a Netty Server?

Tags: deployment, netty

I've developed a Netty application that allows connections through TCP from various devices. However i'm not entirely sure what is the best way to deploy the application for production use. Right now i package it up in a JAR file and run a screen session on the target server like so:

```
screen -S Nettyjava -jar  Server-Netty.jar
```

Is this the recommended way to deploy it or is screen the best option available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) is not the right tool to run a service in production. If the system has to reboot, you will have to relaunch the service by hand. On most current linux distributions, you can handle this with a [systemd service unit file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#). This allows you to define the working directory, the user, the command to run... Here is an example taken from the Unix & Linux StackExchange question [configure java daemon with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320314/configure-java-daemon-with-systemd)

```
[Unit]
Description=Some job
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/tmp/testout
SyslogIdentifier=SocketTest
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "exec java -jar /home/user/programming/tests/java/core/SocketTest/SocketTest.jar"
User=dlt
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

A good practice consists in creating a specific user for running the service and to restrain his right on the filesystem.